# How to install the Epson L350 printer in Ubutu 14.04?

Tags: printing

Kindly instruct me the method step by step. I am just a user not a programmer.
Thank in advance for yr support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download Epson Printer/Fax/Scanner .deb Drivers for Linux [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=18787&DSCCHK=cd4ad419e3805cfac26d6492d12e38fc7da11822)

Open a File Manager Window

[image]

Double-Click on All the Printer/Fax Driver Packages

[image]

After the Printer will be Recognized and Installed

[image]

Download Epson iScan Software on Download Center [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

First Select Only the ‘Scanner Driver’ with ‘core&data‘ packages
Then Get Both ‘iscan2+… ltdl7‘ and ‘iscan-data’ .deb 32/64bit Packages

Open Terminal Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Install iScan for Ubuntu Linux

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
sudo su -c "dpkg -i ./iscan*.deb
```

Launch iScan and Start Scanning

```
iscan
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind answer. I will try as the above suggestion and Will get back if get a problem